# Can multiple Kubernetes NodePort services share the same backend target?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, google-cloud-networking

I am running a cluster on GKE, and one particular http path needs a longer timeout than the load balancer's default 30 seconds. So I want to use a GKE BackendConfig object to extend the timeout, but I don't want to use it for all requests, just this particular path. Can I configure the Ingress to fan out to two NodePorts based on path, one with a BackendConfig with the longer timeout, and then the NodePorts would "fan in" to the same targetPort backend?

Answer (score 0):

I think your can reach your design, following these steps:

1.- Defining 2 BackendConfig:

1.1
apiVersion: cloud.google.com/v1beta1
kind: BackendConfig
metadata:
  name: custom-backend
spec:
  timeoutSec: 40
  connectionDraining:
    drainingTimeoutSec: 60

1.2
apiVersion: cloud.google.com/v1beta1
kind: BackendConfig
metadata:
  name: default-backend
spec:
  timeoutSec: 30
  connectionDraining:
    drainingTimeoutSec: 60

2.- create two services:

2.1 One with the backend with a longer timeout (in this example, custom-backend)

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: custom-service
  labels:
    purpose: bsc-config-demo
  annotations:
    beta.cloud.google.com/backend-config: '{"ports": {"80":"custom-backend"}}'
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    purpose: bsc-config-demo
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080

2.2 Another with the default timeout.

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: default-service
  labels:
    purpose: bsc-config-demo
  annotations:
    beta.cloud.google.com/backend-config: '{"ports": {"80":"default-backend"}}'
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    purpose: bsc-config-demo
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080

3. Create the ingress, defining two different paths:

apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-bsc-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /*
        backend:
          serviceName: default-service
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /folder/*
        backend:
          serviceName: custom-service
          servicePort: 80

A complete guide here:

[Configuring a backend service through Ingress](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/configure-backend-service)

Best Regards.